# Use .htaccess to redirect homepage to its permalink

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

How can I get WordPress to preserve my permalink that I have set for the homepage?

I would like the homepage's URL to be `www.example.com/homepage-title`, not `www.example.com`. Its permalink is already set to `www.example.com/homepage-title`, but on navigation to the site I would like it to redirect to `www.example.com/homepage-title` instead of `www.example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need mod_rewrite for that, a simple [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) is enough:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^$ /homepage-title
```

Place the rule above WordPress’ permalink rules.